# Kendo ui angularjs with virtual scrolling not working

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo ui virtual scrolling is not working while fetching the remote json data. Here is the code

```
<div id= "test-grid" kendo-grid="testGrid" k-options="testGridOptions"></div>

$scope.testGridOptions = {
    dataSource : {
        transport: {
            read: function(e) {
                Service.getdata().then(function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                        $scope.isReqComplete = true;
                        //Response will be {results :[], count:3}
                        e.success(response);
                    }
                });
            },
        },
        schema : {
            type : "json",
        },
        type :"json",
        serverSorting: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: true,
    },
    columns: cols,
    scrollable: {
        virtual: true
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Are you reaching the controller? Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Client side code looks good. I believe that the issue is related to the server side implementation.

You should check that server is implement paging and send total amount of available records.